# for loop plot in list of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, split

I want to make multiple plot.

So I split data frame, and tried to ggplot.

```
linkid <- unique (orgin_dat$stdLinkId)
temp <- split(orgin_dat, orgin_dat$stdLinkId)

p1 <-  ggplot(temp$`1550007100`, aes(x=datetime, y=linkSpeed)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle(linkid[i])
## it works

p1 <-  ggplot(temp$linkid[1], aes(x=datetime, y=linkSpeed)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle(linkid[i])
## it doesn't work
```

My goal is

```
for(i in 1:50){
  assign(paste(p, i, sep=""), 
  ggplot(temp$linkid[i], aes(x=datetime, y=linkSpeed)) +
    geom_line() +
    ggtitle(linkid[i]))
}
## it doesn't work
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does `temp$linkid[1]` produce what you expected it to produce? You may want something like `temp[linkid[1]]` instead, though it'll be hard to troubleshoot the exact problem without knowing what `temp` & `linkid` look like.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to combine `$` and `[` for subsetting a list? Try `temp[[i]]` instead of `temp$linkid[i]`. And I'd recommend using a `list` to store the plots instead of using `assign`. If you post a reproducible example I can try to help more (maybe uses the `mtcars` built-in data?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to reach a definite answer without a reproducible example. However, you could try the following solution that doesn't require splitting your data in the first place:

```
for (i in unique(orgin_dat$stdLinkId)){
  assign(paste0("p", i),
  ggplot(filter(orgin_dat, stdLinkId == i),
         aes(x=datetime, y=linkSpeed)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle(paste0(i))
}
```

NOTE: you will need `library(dplyr)` for the `filter()`.